# How was she able to crack the password of her professor's mail?

Tags: plot-explanation, 7-aum-arivu

The movie [*7aum Arivu*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7aum_Arivu), (meaning  *Seventh sense* in english. This is the title in Telugu) is a 2011 Indian science fiction-martial arts film. It was originally made in Tamil and dubbed into Telugu, Hindi and Malayalam. The movie revolves about a genetic experiment conducted by Subha(female lead starred by Shruti Hassan). She knows that Chinese government is conducting an operation named operation Red.  After some time, Subha and Aravind(protagonist starred by Suriya) learn that Subha's professor from the genetics department is assisting Dong Lee(antagonist starred by Johnny Tri Nguyen) in Operation Red. Subha and Aravind sneak into professor's apartment and know about the details of this operation. Here, Subha and Aravind search his house for details. Subha switches on the Personal Computer of professor and goes through his mails. She enters e-mail ID and password of her professor.

[Watch](https://youtu.be/rQp6yuRANY0?t=5434) it on Youtube.

The computer was not locked. It had no password. How was she able to crack down the password of her professor's mail?

Comment: Password guessing in movies is almost always fantasy and has nothing to do with real world password cracking. I think this is also a common trope: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThePasswordIsAlwaysSwordfish

Comment: @FranciscoV. In the movie, mac is used. A deleted answer to this question said that the password is saved in the browser in the movie. So I was thinking there might be other reasons too or the reason given in the deleted answer might be right.

Comment: @S S; the password to the mail account is stored in the browser, maybe the computer wasn't locked at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No password on the computer account, and the professor saved his password in Safari, so there was nothing to crack/hack. Many people do not require a password to enter their computer and many people save passwords to their browser. Note that the "stay signed in" checkbox for gmail was checked. Most people give little thought to security on their computer.

Comment: Are you sure?  It was a saved password? I don't know how saved passwords look like on mac.

Comment: That's exactly how saved passwords look in Safari. Been using it for like 12 years. Gmail too. It's only on the screen for three or four seconds but if you slow it down you can see, all she does is move the mouse.